# Remove <a> tag from a string by HREF attribute

Tags: python

I have an HTML body, a possible extract:

```
body = 'Hi what <a href="url_example_1" other-attribute>is</a> your <a href="url_example2" other-attribute>name</a>?....other stuffs'
```

This could be more much longer with others HTML tags and maybe others `<a>` too.

I also have one url i want to remove from the body:

```
url_to_remove = 'url_example_1'
```

Is there a regex or other way to get this new body removing `url_to_remove` `<a>` tag?

My new body should be:

```
new_body = 'Hi what is your <a href="url_example2" other-attribute>name</a>?....other stuffs'
```

Comment: It could be built (the regex) but according to what logic should be implemented? (remove the first  occurrences only etc)

Comment: Will the html body be always valid html?

Comment: @andreis11 i have a list of `body` and a related list of `url_to_remove` (one url for each body). there is only one occurrence of that url in the body

Comment: @L3viathan i can't be sure about that

Comment: If your a-tags are really always this simple, and never contain any other attributes, [you could use regex](https://regex101.com/r/Ustu4o/2)

Comment: a-tags could contain other attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

body = 'HTML code here'
to_delete = 'depricated url'
soup = BeautifulSoup(body)
elements = soup.find_all("a")
for element in elements:
    if element['href'] == to_delete:
        element.replace_with("%s" % element.text)
body = soup

print(body)
```

Comment: it is removing the whole <a> tag, i want to keep the text inside it, look at my example